# Where do I find the ga_trackingId for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I am creating a global tracker for firebase analytics for all events.

I am following the instructions from this site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4

The page tells you to add an xml file to your Android project and add your trackingID to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">${YOUR_TRACKING_ID}</string>
</resources>
```

Cleverly, it does not say anywhere in the instruction anything about where the trackingID came from.

Having searched for the answer extensively already, I found that you can create a ga_trackingId in Google Analytics Console... but my team uses the Firebase Analytics Console, and nowhere can I find where I can create a trackingID in Firebase Analytics...

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Any solutions found?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question itself is a bit old. However I spent some time to find *ga_tracking_Id* myself so it might be still useful to answer it to save someone's time.

1. Open Firebase console and then the project you want to get *ga_trackingId*  for
2. Click "Project settings" -> "Integrations" -> at the "Google Analytics" section click "Manage" -> "View in Google Analytics"
3. Once Google analytics page is loaded click on the project name at the top of it
4. The number you'll see below you project name at the "Properties & Apps" column is your project *ga_trackingId*